# Environment.UserName return defaultAppPool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having difficulty getting the User Name of a person logged into a machine.
`Environment.UserName` returns 'defaultAppPool', I need to return the UserName. How deiceded?

Comment: Do you mean the person logged in to your web application?  Because what you're currently getting is the username that's running your IIS worker process.

Comment: I meen person logged in my web application

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following:

Method 1:

```
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Method 2:

```
        private static string GetCurrentUserName()
        {
          string[] pathParts = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
            if (pathParts.Length != 0)
            {
                return pathParts[pathParts.Length - 1];
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: There are limitations to that method - your ASP/IIS authentication modes need to be set to impersonate the end user, for starters.  (Not that there's a much better method, but the prerequisites should be noted.)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you have to use **User.Identity.Name** 
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

then test by :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
else
   Label1.Text = "No user identity available.";
```